# Steps for porting protractor test project from javascript to typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

- installed node and verified npm is working
- added following to package json "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "^7.0.4",
  "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.45",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
  "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
  "jasmine-reporters": "^2.3.1",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
  "prettier": "1.14.3",
  "protractor": "~5.3.0",
  "protractor-beautiful-reporter": "1.2.5",
  "stylelint": "^9.5.0",
  "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.2.0",
  "stylelint-scss": "^3.3.0",
  "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
  "tsc": "^1.20150623.0",
  "tslint": "~5.9.1",
  "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
  }
- ran npm install

Tried to run npm run protractor conf.js

I get this error:
{ import { browser } from 'protractor';
  ^^^^^^

Syntax error unexpected token import.

From my understanding this happens because the project was not transpiled.

This is the step that i am stuck at.
I tried to run ng build, hoping that this will transpile for me,but I get 
another error that my project is not angular.

Any help would be appeciated.

Answer (score 2):

At first you need a `tsconfig.json` next to your `package.json`.

The `tsconfig.json` can look like this (for more detail please see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html)):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist/",
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"  <-- Dynamic path to your test files
    ]
}
```

To compile i suggest to add following to the `scripts` section in your `package.json`:

```
...
"scripts": {
    ....
    "compile": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc"
    ....
}
...
```

After executing `npm run compile` you should have a `dist` directory in your project.

Now to execute your tests you need to adjust the path to your test files in your `conf.js` to from something like this:

`./dist/sample-test.e2e.ts`

to

`./dist/sample-test.e2e.js`

And now you should be able to execute your tests again ;-)

**Update:**
After installing `Typescript` you have an executable in your `./node_modules/.bin` directory, which you need to compile your `*.ts` files to `*.js`.

Comment: Could you add an explanation what `./node_modules/.bin/tsc` does?

Comment: Thank you. If I understand you correctly transpiles this call `./node_modules/.bin/tsc` all *.ts files (typescript) to *.js files (javascript)?