# Typescript not compiling external class - protractor test

Tags: typescript, protractor, typescript-typings

Typescript not compiling external class - protractor test.

I am trying to use external typescript classes, which i published as a npm package, into my protracter test, which is also in typescript. Im compiling typescript with gulp. Everything was working fine, when I had the class in the same project as my test, but now that I'm trying to use it via node_modules as a package, I get errors.

At run time, I get `Unexpected token error`. 
It looks like typescript is not compiling. Is it a typings error? Do I need to generate types for my package?

---

```
import { Helper } from './src/helper';
       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

---

package file system

- e2e/src/helper
- index.ts
- package.json
- tsconfig.json

---

index.ts

```
import { Helper } from './src/helper';
export { Helper };
```

---

package.json

```
  "name": "my-project",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  "version": "0.0.1",
```

---

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "lib",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true,
        "types": [
        ]
    }
}
```

---

TEST

Protractor test file, where I'm trying to use the external class, which has been imported into `node_modules`

test.ts

```
import { Helper } from 'my-project';

describe(' Test Description' , () => {

    let helper: Helper;

before(async () => {
    helper = new Helper();
});
```

---

```
running this test gives me error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Comment: Look like duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227443/steps-for-porting-protractor-test-project-from-javascript-to-typescript

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Helper } from 'my-project';

describe(' Test Description' , () => {

    let helper: Helper;

    before(async () => {
        helper = new Helper();
    });
}); //- сlosing tag
```

Comment: Hi! While this may provide a solution to OP's question, code only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. It is important for OP to understand why this is a solution as it will help them more in the long run and be more beneficial for future visitors of the site. Thanks!